# How to write a query that substrats a value -1?

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to do a simple query that decreases certain value in 1 unit.

I tried this but it seems to be wrong:

`ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN postcounter - 1`

How can I do this simple query?

Comment: Alter is used to change the structure of the table. To change a column value use update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
UPDATE TABLE SET your_column_name = your_column_name - 1;
```

Comment: thanks, in the end this worked `UPDATE users SET postcounter = postcounter - 1`

Comment: it was! but how to validte it?